# Change material of gltf-imported mesh programmatically - react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I'm currently working at a project with react-three-fiber. I've imported the model with useGLTF from @react-three/drei.

With

```
const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/model.glb');
```

I access the materials from the glb-file.
To access and manipulate the model I used gltfjsx to generate the model.

Now I need to change the material of a mesh programmatically. Because I have no direct access to the JSX of the model I do it with `React.cloneElement` and modify the props of the mesh.

So I tried something like this:

```js
return React.cloneElement(mesh, {
  material: overwriteMaterial ?
    <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={0xa3005c} metalness={1} roughness={0.2} visible={true} /> :
    materials['mat_7']
});
```

If `overwriteMaterial` is false it works. It shows the material it should. But if it's true then the mesh disappears.

I also thought of putting the `<meshStandardMaterial />` in the children prop of the mesh. Something like so:

```js
return React.cloneElement(mesh, {
  material: overwriteMaterial ? undefined : materials['mat_7'],
  children: overwriteMaterial ? <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={0xa3005c} metalness={1} roughness={0.2} visible={true} /> : undefined
});
```

With this I always get this error and I don't know why it appears:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible')`

Could this approach somehow work or am I doing something completely wrong?

Every help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I found the answer by myself after some more hours searching for a solution.

The material property doesn't accept a JSX-tag. So if you create an instance of the class `MeshStandardMaterial` you can pass it to the property and it works perfectly fine. Now it looks something like this:

```
return React.cloneElement(mesh, {
  material: overwriteMaterial
  ? new MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x0ff000 })
  : materials['mat_7']
})
```

Note: The class MeshStandardMaterial is exported from the `three` package.

Answer (score 1):

i really don't think you have to clone any react element, that doesn't seem correct. you can clone or mutate materials just as you would in a plain three app. i have no idea why you even want to clone jsx.

```
const { scene } = useGLTF(url)
const clonedScene = useMemo(() => scene.clone(), [])
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  clonedScene.traverse(o => {
    if (o.type === 'Mesh') {
      o.material = ...
    }
  })
}, [clonedScene]}
return <primitive object={clonedScene} />
```

you can skip the clonedScene thing completely as well, this is only if you plan to re-use the model in your scene multiple times.